# How do I activate Top Navigation for the jQuery PageScroller plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'd like help figuring out how to activate the Top Navigation for the PageScroller plugin: site: http://pagescroller.com/

I checked out the generated source for the left navigation and top navigation of the webpage itself and the only changes I noticed are the classes "scrollNav" and "topNav"

#### Left navigation

```
<ul class="pageScroll left" style="display: block;">
<li class="scrollNav scrollNav_1 active"><a href="#pageScroll0">Introduction</a></li>
<li class="scrollNav scrollNav_2"><a href="#pageScroll1">How It Works</a></li>
<li class="scrollNav scrollNav_3"><a href="#pageScroll2">What's Included?</a></li>
<li class="scrollNav scrollNav_4"><a href="#pageScroll3">Documentation</a></li>
<li class="scrollNav scrollNav_5"><a href="#pageScroll4">Download Plugin</a></li></ul>
```

#### Top navigation

```
<div class="topNav white">
<ul style="display: block;">
<li class="topNavLink topNavLink_1 active"><a href="#pageScroll0">Introduction</a></li>
<li class="topNavLink topNavLink_2"><a href="#pageScroll1">How It Works</a></li>
<li class="topNavLink topNavLink_3"><a href="#pageScroll2">What's Included?</a></li>
<li class="topNavLink topNavLink_4"><a href="#pageScroll3">Documentation</a></li>
<li class="topNavLink topNavLink_5"><a href="#pageScroll4">Download Plugin</a></li>
<li class="colors white"><span class="label">COLOR</span><span class="white active">white</span><span class="dark">dark</span></li></ul></div>
```

I changed the navigationClass (in the instantiating function) to "topNav" but it didn't work. I tried "topNav white" but it came out [broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vey4m.png).

Thanks for reading. I'm still learning jQuery and while I can tell that it's pretty powerful, I'll need time working on it to get better. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do the following:

```
$('#main').pageScroller();
$('ul').removeClass('pageScroll left').addClass('topNav');
```

In the beta version of pagescroller.js it kept setting the ul class to "pageScroll left" so the .removeClass method pulls those off and then .addClass allows you to set the topNav class.
With the ul class "topNav" the li's then default to scrollNav.

Once the li's are set to scrollNav the styles change line 264 `.scrollNav {float: left;}`

That should do it.